# MATLAB: Using CONVN for moving average on Matrix

Tags: matlab, convolution

I'm looking for a bit of guidance on using CONVN to calculate moving averages in one dimension on a 3d matrix. I'm getting a little caught up on the flipping of the kernel under the hood and am hoping someone might be able to clarify the behaviour for me.

A similar post that still has me a bit confused is here:

[CONVN example about flipping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27852571/understanding-behaviour-of-matlabs-convn)

**The Problem:**

I have daily river and weather flow data for a watershed at different source locations.

So the matrix is as so,

dim 1 (the rows) represent each site
dim 2 (the columns) represent the date
dim 3 (the pages) represent the different type of measurement (river height, flow, rainfall, etc.)

The goal is to try and use CONVN to take a 21 day moving average at each site, for each observation point for each variable.

As I understand it, I should just be able to use a a kernel such as:

```
ker = ones(1,21) ./ 21.;
mat = randn(150,365*10,4);
avgmat = convn(mat,ker,'valid');
```

I tried playing around and created another kernel which should also work (I think) and set ker2 as:

```
ker2 = [zeros(1,21); ker; zeros(1,21)];
avgmat2 = convn(mat,ker2,'valid');
```

**The question:**

The results don't quite match and I'm wondering if I have the dimensions incorrect here for the kernel. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi! I'm the one who answered the post you've linked to.  Judging from the context, you have a 3D matrix and you want to find the moving average of each row independently over all 3D slices.  The code above should work (the first case).  However, `valid` returns a matrix whose size is valid in terms of the boundaries of the convolution.  If I'm interpreting your question correctly, try using the `same` flag instead of the `valid` flag.  Let me know if that works.  In the meantime, can you please update your post with a bit of sample data on what you think the answer is and what MATLAB returns?

Comment: BTW, you have a symmetric kernel, and so flipping should have no effect on the convolution output.  What you have specified is a standard moving averaging kernel, and so convolution should work in finding the moving average as you expect.... but I'm a bit confused because you said the above doesn't work!

Comment: Hi there. It was the 'valid' flag that was the issue. I was only comparing results at the edges by hand and wasn't looking at the right ones. I almsot want to retract my question now....

Comment: That is completely up to you :). The question you have is a valid one (no pun intended) that trips up a lot of people.  If you do want it to stay, I can write an answer that summarizes what we talked about.  If you want to retract / delete your answer, that's no problem at all.  Let me know what you want to do!

Comment: Feel free to add an answer and I'll flag as solved. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks :) Just did it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the context of your question, you have a 3D matrix and you want to find the moving average of each row independently over all 3D slices. The code above should work (the first case). However, the `valid` flag returns a matrix whose size is valid in terms of the boundaries of the convolution.  Take a look at the first point of the post that you linked to for more details.

Specifically, the first 21 entries for each row will be missing due to the `valid` flag.  It's only when you get to the 22nd entry of each row does the convolution kernel become completely contained inside a row of the matrix and it's from that point where you get valid results (no pun intended).  If you'd like to see these entries at the boundaries, then you'll need to use the `'same'` flag if you want to maintain the same size matrix as the input or the `'full'` flag (which is default) which gives you the size of the output starting from the most extreme outer edges, but bear in mind that the moving average will be done with a bunch of zeroes and so the first 21 entries wouldn't be what you expect anyway.

However, if I'm interpreting what you are asking, then the `valid` flag is what you want, but bear in mind that you will have 21 entries missing to accommodate for the edge cases.  All in all, your code should work, but be careful on how you interpret the results.

BTW, you have a symmetric kernel, and so flipping should have no effect on the convolution output. What you have specified is a standard moving averaging kernel, and so convolution should work in finding the moving average as you expect.

---

Good luck!